# Can Ubuntu One work with Mac Time Machine?

Tags: mac

Is is possible to set Mac's Time Machine to use Ubuntu One? There's no info on Mac Help.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you split the question in two parts: 1. How can a mac access Ubuntu One? 2. What targets does time machine support? Then, see if the answers match. Both questions are better asks in a Mac community.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's Time Machine does not support Ubuntu One, and as far as I know there is no Ubuntu One client for OS X at all.

Time Machine only backs up to HFS+-formatted disks connected directly to the machine or via AFP.